# In VBA I want an if/elseif to execute based on the OS i.e. if windows do this, if mac do this. How do I do this?

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen this code online:

```
Dim TheOS As String
TheOS = Application.Operatingsystem
```

But I don't really understand how to implement that code to display what the OS is so I can test it

Comment: `If TheOS Like "Mac*" Then`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in compilation argument Mac:

```
#If Mac Then
    ' Code for the Mac
#Else
    ' Code for Windows
#End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will return 1 if the operating system is Windows, else 2.

```
Function OS() As Long

    Dim OSname As String
    
    OSname = Application.OperatingSystem
    If InStr(1, OSname, "windows", vbTextCompare) Then
        ' do one thing
        OS = 1
    Else
        ' do another
        OS = 2
    End If
End Function
```

You can examine the `OSname` string further, to determine which version of Windows or MAC. You can use the above code directly or indirectly, meaning, you may take different action within the function or use the result it returns to take different action.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like just what I need! I'm a beginner. Do you mind explaining what the integers in your code mean. ex. the 1 in " If InStr(1, OSname, "windows", vbTextCompare) Then" or the 2 after the Else

Comment: The numbers don't really mean anything, other than just way to differentiate between whether it's a windows machine or not.

Comment: Save my function to a standard code module (by default its name will be like *Module1*). Then, in a worksheet in the same workbook where you pasted the function, type `=OS()` in any blank cell. The cell will display a 1 if your computer runs on Windows or a 2 if it does not. Now change the formula to `=IF(OS() = 1, "Windows", "Other system")` for a demonstration of what to do with the numbers.